# How do i test postman when i have passport authentication

Tags: node.js, postman, passport.js

Im trying to test using postman but i have a passport authentication which is blocking me from testing as it will redirect me to the login screen it is not authenticated.

How i can get a token or authenticate myself in postman to be able to test

I have tried to use /auth/local in postman but it just returns that i cant get the route

Passport.js

```
var LocalStrategy = require('passport-local').Strategy;
var { User } = require('../model/user.js');
var bcrypt = require('bcrypt');

module.exports = function (passport) {
passport.use(new LocalStrategy(function (username, password, done) {
let query = { username: username };
User.findOne(query, function (err, user) {
  if (err) throw err;
  if (!user) {
    return done(null, false,{ message: 'No user found' });
  }

  bcrypt.compare(password, user.password, function (err, isMatch) {
    if (err) throw err;
    if (isMatch) {
      return done(null, user);
    } else { 
      return done(null, false,{ message: 'Wrong password' });
    }
  });
  });
 }));

  passport.serializeUser(function (user, done) {
  done(null, user.id);
  });

   passport.deserializeUser(function (id, done) {
    User.findById(id, function (err, user) {
  done(err, user);
   });
  });
}
```

Route.js

```
router.get('/register', function (req, res) {
res.sendFile(__dirname + "/views/register.html");

  });


  router.post('/register', async (req, res) => {

var data = req.body;
var salt = await bcrypt.genSalt(10)
var hashedpw = await bcrypt.hash(data.password, salt)
const newUser = await User.create({
    name: data.name,
    email: data.email,
    username: data.username,
    password: hashedpw,
   });
newUser.save();
req.flash('success', 'You are now registered and can log in');
res.redirect('/');


  });


router.get('/login', function (req, res) {
res.locals.success = req.flash('success');
res.locals.error = req.flash('message');
res.render(__dirname + "/views/login.ejs");

});

 router.post('/login', async (req, res, next) => {
  passport.authenticate('local', {
    successRedirect: '/',
    failureRedirect: '/login',
    failureFlash: true
    })(req, res, next);
  });

    router.get('/logout', async (req, res) => {
     req.logout(function (err) {
    if (err) { return next(err); }
    req.flash('success', 'You are logged out');
    res.redirect("/")
      });
   });
     function ensureAuthenticated(req, res, next) {
    if (req.isAuthenticated()) {
    return next();
     } else {
    res.redirect('/login');
    }
     }
```

Comment: Your loginpage probably does some sort of API call? Do that with postman as first request and save the resulting token in a postman environment variable. Then use this environment variable in subsequent requests

Answer (score 1):

Following this guide:
https://mevelix.com/articles/postman-auth-for-laravel,4

you have to create the Command:

```
php artisan make:command DevPostman
```

then in the newly created class, copy the content **it is showed in the link,**
inside the class namespace App\Console\Commands\DevPostmanCommand

Then you can execute the command:

```
php artisan dev:postman web
```

in this way you are creating a simulated session.

This is my ouput, for example:

[image]

you paste this output directly in PostMan, inside the Tab Pre-Request Scripts:

[image]

In this way you are allowed to avoid the login inside Postman, because you are simulating a session.

See the first link to have the complete code of the DevPostmanCommand class.